# Box Shadow getting clipped on Css Grid Masonry effect

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to solve an issue with a box shadow style getting clipped on a css grid implementation. The last card item has the shadow cut off as if there was no padding after it.

There is generous padding on the container ".masonry"... why would this happen? See the CSS, HTML and Screenshot below.

[image]

```css
.masonary {
  column-width: 33%;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 2em;
}

.masonary div {
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}

.pv5 {
  padding-top: 4rem;
  padding-bottom: 4rem
}

.brick:nth-child(5n+2) {
  border-color: #74398D;
}
.masonary div {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}
.bg-white {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}
.shadow-6 {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.mb4 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.ph4 {
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}
.pv3 {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}
.bw2 {
  border-width: 0.25rem;
}
.br2 {
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
.bt {
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="masonary pv5">
  <div class="brick mb4 ph4 pv3 w-100 br2 bg-white bt bw2 shadow-6">
      <h3>Process screening and optimisation</h3>
      <ul class="nl3">
        <li class="">One</li>
        <li class="">Two</li>
        <li class="">Three</li>
        <li class="">Four</li>
        <li class="">Five</li>
      </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="brick mb4 ph4 pv3 w-100 br2 bg-white bt bw2 shadow-6">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Hello World</p>
      <ul class="nl3">
          <li class="">One</li>
          <li class="">Two</li>
          <li class="">Three</li>
      </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="brick mb4 ph4 pv3 w-100 br2 bg-white bt bw2 shadow-6">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p>Hello World</p>
          <ul class="nl3">
              <li class="">One</li>
              <li class="">Two</li>
              <li class="">Three</li>
          </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="brick mb4 ph4 pv3 w-100 br2 bg-white bt bw2 shadow-6">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Hello World</p>
      <ul class="nl3">
          <li class="">One</li>
          <li class="">Two</li>
          <li class="">Three</li>
      </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="brick mb4 ph4 pv3 w-100 br2 bg-white bt bw2 shadow-6">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Hello World</p>
      <ul class="nl3">
          <li class="">One</li>
          <li class="">Two</li>
          <li class="">Three</li>
          <li class="">Four</li>
          <li class="">Five</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code in the question doesn't reproduce the example shown in the image.  This is possibly because the `box-shadow` is overrunning the edge of the parent element in belongs to and is therefore getting clipped.

Answer (score 1):

The box-shadow is getting clipped because its overflowing the parent div element. Increasing the bottom padding will fix your problem.